# Any way to make jQuery.inArray() case insensitive?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Title sums it up.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [each(](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/))...

```
// Iterate over an array of strings, select the first elements that 
// equalsIgnoreCase the 'matchString' value
var matchString = "MATCHME".toLowerCase();
var rslt = null;
$.each(['foo', 'bar', 'matchme'], function(index, value) { 
  if (rslt == null && value.toLowerCase() === matchString) {
    rslt = index;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: You will want to add a "return false;" at the end of that if statement so the 'each' doesn't continue after a matching element is found. (In jQuery.each() "return false;" is equivalent to "break;" in a regular JavaScript loop.)

Comment: Isn't it toLowerCase rather than toLower?

Comment: Technically InArray() returns -1 if not found.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to store the `matchString.toLowerCase()` value in a variable before the loop instead of computing it for each iteration?

Comment: I don't think `equals` is a native method in JavaScript? I think that should be `===`, right?

Answer (score 30):

In case anyone wanted a more integrated approach using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery):

```
(function($){
    $.extend({
        // Case insensative $.inArray (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/)
        // $.inArrayIn(value, array [, fromIndex])
        //  value (type: String)
        //    The value to search for
        //  array (type: Array)
        //    An array through which to search.
        //  fromIndex (type: Number)
        //    The index of the array at which to begin the search.
        //    The default is 0, which will search the whole array.
        inArrayIn: function(elem, arr, i){
            // not looking for a string anyways, use default method
            if (typeof elem !== 'string'){
                return $.inArray.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            // confirm array is populated
            if (arr){
                var len = arr.length;
                    i = i ? (i < 0 ? Math.max(0, len + i) : i) : 0;
                elem = elem.toLowerCase();
                for (; i < len; i++){
                    if (i in arr && arr[i].toLowerCase() == elem){
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
            // stick with inArray/indexOf and return -1 on no match
            return -1;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this should be added to the jQuery API, copy-pasting it every time would be hard, fine anyway

Comment: This is awesome. It just needs a right curly brace at the beginning of the last line.

Comment: Why the `$.extend({ inArrayIn: function ...` rather than just `$.inArrayIn = function ...`?

Comment: @Luke: No particular reason other than its one of the ways to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you to @Drew Wills.

I rewrote it as this:

```
function inArrayCaseInsensitive(needle, haystackArray){
    //Iterates over an array of items to return the index of the first item that matches the provided val ('needle') in a case-insensitive way.  Returns -1 if no match found.
    var defaultResult = -1;
    var result = defaultResult;
    $.each(haystackArray, function(index, value) { 
        if (result == defaultResult && value.toLowerCase() == needle.toLowerCase()) {
            result = index;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You will have to fiddle with your data, I usually make all my strings lowercase for easy comparisons. There is also the possibility of using a custom comparison function which would do the necessary transforms to make the comparison case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

could loop through the array and toLower each element and toLower what you're looking for, but at that point in time, you may as well just compare it instead of using inArray()

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have to implement your own solution to this. [Here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-add-your-own-custom-functions-to.html) is a good article on adding custom functions to jQuery. You will just need to write a custom function to loop and normalize the the data then compare.

Answer (score 1):

These days I prefer to use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for tasks like this:

```
a = ["Foo","Foo","Bar","Foo"];

var caseInsensitiveStringInArray = function(arr, val) {
    return _.contains(_.map(arr,function(v){
        return v.toLowerCase();
    }) , val.toLowerCase());
}

caseInsensitiveStringInArray(a, "BAR"); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me..

```
var sColumnName = "Some case sensitive Text"

if ($.inArray(sColumnName.toUpperCase(), getFixedDeTasksColumns().map((e) => 
e.toUpperCase())) == -1) {// do something}
```

Comment: This works great for me, and I think it should be the accepted answer!