# Search inArray & form textarea?

Tags: jquery, arrays, textfield

Currently searching array (inArray < 0). My new objective is to determine if the forms textarea :contains a match to new.value

[Search array inArray but ignore case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102429/search-array-inarray-but-ignore-case)

If someone can offer some tips or suggestions, Ill be on my way. Ive spent way to much time on what i currently have......not expecting exact answer. TIA

This new condition would need to initiate on submit() since the user will be complete with the prior fields and most likely not tab/click any where else.

http://jsfiddle.net/arkjoseph/dRpmq/5/

```
  $(submit).submit(function() {
   var data = $(textfield).val();
   //contains some string 
     if(data.indexOf('yourstring') > -1){
     //do this
   }else {
     // do this    
   }

    });
```

Where do I obtain yourstring?

Answer (score 0):

yeah , below ex for get particular string from data .

```
var data = $("#ID").val();//contains some string 
if(data.indexOf('yourstring') > -1){
    //do this
}else {
     // do this    
}
```