# JavaScript: Case Insenstive Array Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a case like,

```
var givenTerms = [Tree, Plant, River, Ocean, Place, Sky];
var check = 'SKY';
if ($.inArray(check, givenTerms()) !== -1) {
    // say it is present in givenTerms
}
```

This case fails as it is case sensitive. I could not use `givenTerms.toLowercase()` as it is an array and not a single term. Is there any other possibility to make this if case true.

Any suggestion could be helpful.

Comment: You can use regex. `new RegExp("SKY", "i")`

Comment: Always have constant array in lower case and compare it with the same case...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to make jQuery.inArray() case insensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390930/any-way-to-make-jquery-inarray-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update/Create a new array for matching string. Here I update the original collection that match search term. [Check the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YABgo.png)

```
var givenTerms = [Tree, Plant, River, Ocean, Place, Sky];
var check = 'SKY';  
givenTerms = ((givenTerms.toString()).toUpperCase()).split(",");
if (givenTerms.indexOf(check) >= 0) {
    alert(check +" found at "+ givenTerms.indexOf(check));
}
```