# jQuery inArray don't detect same word

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array with JavaScript.

```
var arrays = ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'Bing'];

console.log( $.inArray( 'Google', arrays ) ); // return -1
console.log( $.inArray( 'google', arrays ) ); // return 0
```

I want return always `-1` for booth `Google`, `google`, `GOOGLE`, `gooGle`, or other character combined with lowercase and uppercase.

*Google only example, the words is dynamic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390930/any-way-to-make-jquery-inarray-case-insensitive

Comment: *return always -1 for both Google, google, GOOGLE, gooGle*? did you mean? *return always 0 for both Google, google, GOOGLE, gooGle*.

Comment: return `-1` for "Google"? But that is present in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your question, you've meant:

```
I want return always 0 for booth Google, google, GOOGLE, gooGle 
                     ^
```

The jQuery function `$.inArray` executes case-sensitive comparison, so, `G !== g`

What you can do, is convert to either upper or lower case both `Google` string and values within `Arrays`.  Further, your array `arrays` will contain the original values after the conversion.

With function `map` you can accomplish that very smoothly.

```js
var arrays = ['Google', 'Yahoo', 'Bing'];

console.log($.inArray('Google'.toUpperCase(), arrays.map((e) => e.toUpperCase())));
console.log($.inArray('google'.toUpperCase(), arrays.map((e) => e.toUpperCase())));

console.log(arrays);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See? was printed `0` for both executions and your array `arrays` contains the same values.

## Resources

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`jQuery.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: Nice!  Glad you got your answer in before they marked it duplicate as this answer is much better than the answers in the other post.